# building a form with dynamic fields in progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl

I am trying to display a list of open indents with check boxes before them each line. Based on the selection a report will be generated next with further details.

```
Table: xxind_mstr (xxind_nbr, xxind_shipto, xxind_askedby, xxind_date).
```

Is there any way that I can bring the records from xxind_mstr and place them in the FORM with check boxes ?

Answer (score 0):

Note:  This only works if dynamic.  Never hardcode this approach.

Name each check box with the value of ROWID(xxind_mstr).

This way on the post you can read back through the each xxind_mstr getting the value of the the rowid.

Rod

Comment: Yeah. This seems a fair idea @Rod. I will give it a try. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like some more info, just to know if I'm not talking rubbish here. You want to display the records in xxind_mstr as checkboxes, then upon selection of the report setup, fire the report respecting the checkboxes flagged? If so, then I'd use a browse pre-built with a temp-table containing the xxind_mstr records, and a "flagged" field, this being a logical view-as checkbox, and when they run the report, do a

FOR EACH ttxxind_mstr WHERE flagged = true, and you should have what you want.

Comment: Thanks @bupereira for your nice trick. But I actually need to display all the records in the form first, not in a browser.

Comment: And I am so sorry for my late response. Actually was out of touch for a month at all.